# active_admin toggle scope with filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an active admin page that I would like to have a filter that toggles the use of a scope:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :bar, where( ... )
end

ActiveAdmin.register Foo do
  filter :bar, :as => :select, :collection => {:true => nil, :false => false }
end
```

but I get `undefined method`bar_eq' for #

and I still get that even if I define a scope bar_eq on Foo.

How can I toggle a scope on and off in active_admin

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :bar, where( ... )
end

ActiveAdmin.register Foo do
  scope :all, default: true
  scope :bar
end
```